# Azure to AWS migration

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, virtual-machine

What strategy you will recommend in order to move Linux VM deployed currently in Azure to AWS?
Assume that I will fit all the data in the OS disk, so only one disk has to be moved.

The VM is running Linux Ubuntu if that matters.

Naturally I will like to do that with as little network traffic as possible, since it is chargeable.

I read comments about the image making procedure [described here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/), that it is not safe and some of the VMs are lost in the process ... Not sure if it is still the case, but I will hate very much to lose my VM. :)

Comment: hey can I migrate azure mobile service to amazon mobile service ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [Export VM from Azure using CloudXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer) and then [Import the VM in EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/).

Comment: Is there a way to make an image or maybe just a tar.gz file from inside the VM, without the need to stop it?

Something that can be unpacked latter on working other VM of same OS.
Obviously without the Network setting, DHCP leases and so ...